# Jquery not working in cshtml page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to use the `@(ViewData["value"]);` in `document.ready`. But when I use the 
`@(ViewData["value"])` all jQuery not working. My sample given below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = @(ViewData["value"]); // remove this line query has been working 
    if (test != null){
        //my code
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe this one help you var test = @(serializer.Serialize(ViewData["value"]));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using C# inside script tag you need to enclose the C# variable in quotes. Try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         var test = '@(ViewData["value"])'; 
           if (test != null){
     }
    });
```

If the value of your ViewData["value"] is number it's okay if you don't enclose it in quotes but if it is string with spaces for example ViewData["value"]="Hello World" your browser will get an error saying "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" that's why your scripts or jquery will no longer work.

Answer (score 3):

instead of accessing `@(ViewData["value"]);` inside javascript, it's better to put that value inside a hidden field or other element. look at code bellow:

```
<input id="some-id" type="hidden" value="@(ViewData["value"]);" />

...
...
...
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = $("#some-id");
    if (test != null){
       //my code
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer is good but in highly-optimized web application is not acceptable. Imagine your web application that calls ViewData["value"] returns data with 20kb size then you store the 20kb size to a hidden field which in return added 20kb to your page size therefore a total of 40kb is added to your entire web process

Answer (score 1):

ViewData is not accessible on client, because it exists only on view rendering.
possible option

1. serialize your view data to json on server side
2. write it to hidden field, and them parse it to javascript object on client side.

Comment: IMHO what the OP trying to do is also a possible option : accessing `ViewData` when rendering the script

Answer (score 0):

If your `ViewData["value"]` is a `string`, you can try this :

```
var test = '@ViewData["value"]';
```